# Using Zoom to Correctly Scale Differing Screen Sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, screen-resolution

I'm trying to make my website look the same regardless of screen size and I figured using zoom would be the easiest way to do this. I was planning on using screen.height and screen.width to check what the correct proportions for zoom would be, but am running into a problem. A macbook with a height of 13 inches measure out to have a screen.height of 900 pixels but a laptop with a height of 15 inches only has a screen.height of 864 pixels. Is the pixel type returned by screen.height not css pixels but actual digital pixels? Why do you think I'm running into this issue and is there an easier way to check the screen size so that a properly computed zoom variable can run? Thanks in advance!

TLDR: What would the code for the proper zoom values of varying monitor sizes look like if a 15-inch laptop's zoom should be 100%.